# How to use update_attributes for datetime_select helper in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I used mongodb as my database and the driver mongoid.

One of my model `Bill` has a field is local_time, and I used datetime_select in the view:

```
.ym-fbox-select                    
  = f.label :local_time, "Time"
  = f.datetime_select :local_time
```

the `create` action is OK. But the `update` action is not.
The error is like this:

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
    def local_time(1i)=(value)
```

and the `update` is :

```
def update                                   
 @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])             

 respond_to do |format|                     
   if @bill.update_attributes(params[:bill])
```

So I want to know how to update the `local_time` field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes` to your model, just as you would for Timestamps.

See: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/892#issuecomment-1247311

Comment: The link isn't found!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Peter has said I want to include that 
 
**include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes**   should be below  **include Mongoid::Document**    
 As given [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/rails.html#multi_param)